# Handling unhandled exceptions

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have an application where I load an image dynamically. Let's say, that image doesn't exists and we want to notify the user and then exit. In my main loop, I have exception handling which works just fine when I'm reading files with StreamReader. However, if I am throwing exception from another function, the app just crashes and in the error report I see thrown exception (IOException). To get an idea of the app:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    try {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load(myFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Opening failure.");
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    } 
}

public void Load(string imgPath)
{
    string tmpStr;
    string[] tmp;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("myFile.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default)) {
        while ((tmpStr = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
            tmp = tmpStr.Split(' ');

            ...
        }
    }
}

    private void Grid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            ...
            if (!File.Exists(myFile)) {
                throw new IOException("File doesnt exist");
            }
            ...
    }
```

BUT, if I put try-catch block inside Grid_Click, it catches that exception.

Comment: *"Handling unhandled exceptions"* - And that would be an oxymoron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception that is thrown in `Grid-Click` would not be caught by the `catch` statement in the `MainWindow()` method by design, since the method call to `Grid_Click` is not inside that `try` block.

The `Grid_Click` method is called when the click event is fired, which is at an asynchronous time. Only `IOException`s thrown inside the `try` block in `MainWindow` will be caught by that `catch` statement you have listed above.

Answer (score 1):

What you call 'main loop' is just a constructor. The code does not execute under it's control.